# Rigging issue in single object

Tags: rigging

I am facing a problem while rigging this cushion, If I click on Automatic weight, it is not working, If I click on Bone only one vertex is controlling the whole body, Kindly guide me how to fix it
[image]

[image]

[image]

File :
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ZMZ9sORy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZMZ9sORy/)

here it is

Answer (score 2):

Your object is too small, which makes the mesh too dense, therefore the parentage failure. To fix that, scale up both the armature and mesh (like x10), then parent again and it will work. Then you can scale down if needed. Also don't forget to apply the scale.

Comment: Thankyou it's working, but hair aren't moving it with

Comment: put the Armature modifier above the ParticleSystem modifier @Huzaifa Rafiq